# Adding SelectQueryField Id attribute in Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to assign Id attribute to the SelectQueryField in Jinja.
The problem is Jinja don't render variable in double curly brackets.

```
<form method="post" class="form form-inline" >
{{ form.opcje(class="form-control form-select", id="{{user.id}}" ) }}
</form>
```

output:

```
<select class="form-control form-select" id="{{user.id}}" name="opcje"><option selected="" value="__None">Wybierz cechę</option><option value="1">Sklepy</option><option value="2">Niemcy</option><option value="3">Holandia</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<form method="post" class="form form-inline" >
{{ form.opcje(class="form-control form-select", id=user.id ) }}
</form>
```

You can use variables inside the first set of `{{...}}` freely.